# Excel VBA: AutoFill Column Down Without Preset Range

Tags: vba, excel

How do i get Auto-fill to automatically detect the next new ID# to duplicate in the following line without having to tell/ set the excel range where the next ID# would start?

Below is the formula.

```
Sub NewTestRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

copySheet.Range("E3:K500").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

LRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(2, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LRow, 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


copySheet.Range("M3:S500").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[EXAMPLE FORMAT IMAGE]

[image]

Comment: Can you say if cell to right = "Account" then cell = cell above? i.e. for current activecell  if cell.offset( ,1) = "Account"  then cell = cell.offset(-1,0)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you mention Autofill, but you don't use it, you are simply copying ranges... does your destination have empty rows between one range and the second to be pasted?

Comment: If your **Table** is not just a table-looking range of cells, formulas will auto fill as new entry takes place. Adding new row of data by VBA will be different approach though. Alternatively use Named Ranges with formulas (dynamic) for your "AutoFill".

Answer (score 0):

This code cycles through cells in the first column, and checks that it is the same as the proceeding cell in the first column. Also, I'd change "LRow =" to a better way of finding the last row, just in case there are any gaps in your data.

```
LRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

' --- low
While i < LRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        ' --- new ID not found, increment to next row
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf
        ' --- Put whatever code you want to fire when a new ID is found
        NewIDFound = i + 1
    End If
Wend
```